# ipad does not properly recognize mirroring to mac

Tags: ipad

I want to share a note in Notability app on my ipad as a white board for an online Zoom lesson. 
For that I connect my ipad to my mac through cable, and mirror my ipad screen to my mac using the Zoom application's option of share of ipad via cable.

The ipad's screen *is*  mirrored, namely, appears on my mac (usually, sometimes it doesn't and I have know idea why). However, the ipad's Screen Mirroring window (accessed via the ipad's control center) is stuck in a weird intermediate state: it keeps thinking and does not show any devices,  but does show a Stop Mirroring button. In addition, Notability app in the ipad does not recognize the mirroring and does not enable the new presentation mode (but rather keeps showing the Send-to button instead of the display-mode button). For some reason, the mirroring occasionally does work fine, but usually it doesn't, and I cannot replicate what causes it to work.

How can this be fixed?

(My mac, ipad and notability are all updated: versions 10.15.4, 13.4, 9.3.1 respectively.)